# Facebook : The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta

I read a lot of posts about this but none of the solutions seems to work in my case. I learned a lot of stuff reading all these but my problem is still there.

I always get this error message :

> The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

But in my source code there is :

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.shootmeagain.com/photo/Y2013/3769/saintvitus-oslo_30-03-2013_17.jpg" />
```

All my header is here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"><head><title>PHOTOS : Saint Vitus à Oslo (Rockefeller) le 30-03-2013 | Shoot Me Again Webzine.</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel=canonical href='http://www.shootmeagain.com/photos/3769_saintvitus_oslo_30-03-2013'>

<meta property="og:description" content="PHOTOS : Saint Vitus à Oslo (Rockefeller) le 30-03-2013 | Shoot Me Again Webzine." />
<meta property="og:title" content="PHOTOS : Saint Vitus à Oslo (Rockefeller) le 30-03-2013 | Shoot Me Again Webzine." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.shootmeagain.com/photos/3769_saintvitus_oslo_30-03-2013" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.shootmeagain.com/photo/Y2013/3769/saintvitus-oslo_30-03-2013_17.jpg" />
<meta property='fb:admins' content='erikshootmeagain' />
<meta property='fb:app_id' content='146373435406736' />

<link rel=stylesheet href='http://www.shootmeagain.com/layout.css' type='text/css'>
<link rel=stylesheet href='http://www.shootmeagain.com/layout600.css' type='text/css'>
<link rel=stylesheet href='http://www.shootmeagain.com/layout900.css' type='text/css'>
<link rel=stylesheet href='http://www.shootmeagain.com/layout1200.css' type='text/css'>
<link rel=stylesheet href='http://www.shootmeagain.com/layout1600.css' type='text/css'>
<link rel=stylesheet href='http://www.shootmeagain.com/layout1900.css' type='text/css'>
<link rel=stylesheet href='http://www.shootmeagain.com/layoutheight.css' type='text/css'>
<link rel=stylesheet href='http://www.shootmeagain.com/js/jquery-ui-1.11.3.custom/jquery-ui.css' type='text/css'>
<link rel=stylesheet href='http://www.shootmeagain.com/js/jquery-ui-1.11.3.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css' type='text/css'>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.shootmeagain.com/images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="http://www.shootmeagain.com/images/animated_favicon1.gif">

<meta name='keywords' content='webzine, chroniques, photos, interview, concours, mp3, video, hardcore, rock, emo, screamo, metal, punk, garage'>
<meta name='author' content='ChamO'>
<meta name='publisher' content='ChamO'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="fr">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.shootmeagain.com/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.shootmeagain.com/js/jquery-ui-1.11.3.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.shootmeagain.com/js/editPost.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here is an URL for example : http://www.shootmeagain.com/photos/3769_saintvitus_oslo_30-03-2013

Does anybody have an idea ?

Thanks a lot !
Erik

Comment: Looks like you are randomly switching the og:image on every page load …? That is not a good idea. Facebook caches this data, so it won’t have the desired effect anyway. Keep your OG meta data constant, instead of changing it all the time – that is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by adding the `og:image` `width`, `height`, `alt` and `secure_url` properties on separate lines:

```
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
  <meta property="og:image:alt" content="description_of_site">
  <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://your_domain/my_og_image.png">
```

That should pass.

FB also complains if the `fb:app_id` is missing too, but you can leave that out.